# Error when generating migrations via CLI with Nest and TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, database-migration

I am trying to generate migrations based on my entities, so I configured the DataSource. However, when I run the command to generate the migrations, nothing happens.

**DataSource:**

```js
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'docker',
  database: 'postgres',
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/db/migrations/*.js'],
  migrationsTableName: 'custom_migration_table',
  synchronize: false,
};

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;
```

**Scripts:**

```json
"typeorm": "npm run build && npx typeorm -d dist/db/data-source.js",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate",
"migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
"migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert"
```

**Command:**

```bash
yarn migration:generate ./src/db/migrations/create_user.ts
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: it says no changes were found, you have to create new migration of there are no changes. "typeorm migration:create ./src/db/migrations/create_user.ts"

Comment: @Rationalist I believe that's not the case, especially since the creation command also displays the same error. I need them to be automatically generated from my entities.

Comment: @LayTexas i'm also running into this, did you solve your issue?